# PHP - Is require_once is a function or is it a language keyword?

Tags: php

I have noticed in php,

```
<?php   
require_once( 'page_elements.php' );
?>
```

OR you can write it as

```
<?php   
require_once 'page_elements.php';
?>
```

is there a different in these ? is it really function or is it a language keyword ? Also is there any performance/or any difference in these two syntax ?

Comment: Sometimes a quick look at the reference manual can save you a heap of time: [PHP include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 1):

both are identical, they may be a minor (to the point of undetectable) speed decrease by using the brackets.

The brackets are really part of the string expression (and are fairly pointless. )

Answer (score 0):

`require_once` is a *"language construct"*, essentially a keyword if you will. The parentheses make no difference whatsoever; actually, they belong more to the string than to the `require_once`. You can put any expression into as many parentheses as you want:

```
foo((((1 + 2) + 3)));
```

Unless it influences operator precedence, the parentheses have no effect whatsoever.

See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

require_once is a php statement and while using statements we must avoid (). whenever we use `require_once '...';` or `include_once '...';` statements, these are directly go for `require('...')` and `include('...')` respectively. 
Take another reference of return statement.

```
return $i;
return($i);
```

there is no difference between these two lines if we are talking about the output. But we don't use braces with return.